# docker compose containers not able to access internet

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, centos, centos8

I'm using `docker-compose` to build and run containers. this containers not able to access internet. but when using `docker` to build and run containers. this containers able to access internet.

> NOTE: I'm trying to access internet with this command `apt update`

> NOTE: When add `network_mode: bridge` or `network_mode: host` to `docker-compose.yml` it will be able to access internet.

```
os: centos 8
docker: 19.03.12 
docker-compose: 1.26.0
```

`docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 mongo_db:
    command: mongod --auth
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXX
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions below. for more details look this [Issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/955) and [Answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8).

1. Add the `docker0` interface to firewall trusted zone.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --reload
```

2. Define bridge network and use it in docker compose. [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/).
3. Disable firewall **(bad one)**.